# can anyone explain me encoding in Kivy?

Tags: python, kivy, arabic, persian

I don't know how to type in other language in kivy. Can anyone help me with a simple example?

```
Button:
    text: "hello"
    size_hint_x: 25
    background_color: (1.0, 2.0, 2.0, 1.0)
```

In above code I have a button that contains text "hello" in that,and I want to replace "hello" with foreign language, I want to know what should I put in that code to support other language?

Comment: You mean non ascii letters?